# Memory Leak initWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

I just finished running my application through instruments and I am leaking _NSCFDictionaries out of control. I do not have a @property set up for workoutArray as it is a private instance variable.

```
NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSArray *rawDump = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
workoutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dict in rawDump){
    [workoutArray addObject: dict];
}

[rawDump release];
```

I release workoutArray in -dealloc

```
 - (void)dealloc {
[workoutArray release];
[managedObjectContext release];
[df release];
[super dealloc];
```

}

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this in a thread?  You may need an NSAutoreleasePool.

Comment: Is that code called multiple times?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not running the method twice (or more)?

Comment: @Bill workoutArray becomes nil if I autorelease

Comment: @Eiko and @Roman Yes this is my home screen it is called more than once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you indicate you run this more than once (on the same instance), then the problem is that you reassign your `workoutArray` without releasing the old object. You need to `release` the old object before reassigning:

```
[workoutArray release];
workout Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // etc.
```

As `workoutArray` as an ivar is nil by default on the first time, this should always work correctly.